# Android Studio: Fixing gradle-wrapper and re-importing project is taking too long

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm following a tutorial from Udacity and they provide me with a sample code from GitHub:

```
https://github.com/udacity/DictionaryProviderExample.git
```

When I try to import or open the project, I get an error saying `Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 2.10`.

I clicked on *Fix `gradle-wrapper` and re-import project*, but it's been 30 minutes and it's still not finished.

I'm running Android Studio 2.1.1 on Mac.

Is it supposed to take this long? Is there any way I can get around the Gradle requirement error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download This intended version:

https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip

Extract and copy it to :

```
C:\Users\{yourUsername}\.gradle\wrapper\dists
```